# Cordova Youtube App - sorting videos

Tags: cordova, youtube

So I'm working on this Youtube Channel app that I've developed with Cordova and it all went very well until I had to sort the videos newest first. 
So I have this code:

```
channelID: string = ‘[xxxxx]’;<BR/>
maxResults: string = ’10’;<BR/>
pageToken: string;<BR/>
googleToken: string = ‘[xxxxx]’;<BR/>
searchQuery: string = ”;<BR/>
```

I tried adding:

```
order: 'date'
```

but nothing happend.

I would really apreciate some help, thank you :)